# Suggestion on incremental backup software

Tags: windows, backup

Given the following example

-- Drive to backup
D:\Data
D:\Data\docs
D:\Data\docs\mydoc1.txt
D:\Data\docs\mydoc2.txt
D:\Data\readme.txt

-- Full Backup result
E:\Backup\Full\Data
E:\Backup\Full\Data\docs
E:\Backup\Full\Data\docs\mydoc1.txt
E:\Backup\Full\Data\docs\mydoc2.txt
E:\Backup\Full\Data\readme.txt

-- Incremental backup result (e.g. files mydoc3.txt and updated readme.txt)
E:\Backup\Inc\Data\docs\mydoc3.txt
E:\Backup\Inc\Data\readme.txt

The full backup is quite simple to achieve cause its simply a copy of the original folder. However, the incremental backup part is tricky cause i want to output in the above file/folder structure. I've searched a few backup solutions but the output of the incremental backup is 1 big file and it contains the changes.

Is there a backup solution that will achieve the above example?

Comment: There are many backup programs that are capable of incremental backups.  This question is too wide open and should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

[HoboCopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hobocopy/).  It has a --incremental flag (i think that's it) that uses a timestamp from a file for its last backup date.  It also does shadow copies, so is ideal for backing up.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Bvckup](http://bvckup.com). It does what you want in its default configuration.

Comment: I've had good results with Bvckup. Excellent UI.

Answer (score 1):

How about robocopy? You could script different types for a full and inc backup and schedule them to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Handy Backup](http://www.handybackup.net). It stores the files the way you described at least to online storage.

Or as understood what you had described. If you meant the merging two files mydoc1.txt and mydoc2.txt into mydoc3.txt then I doubt that any software does that because it's kinda ridiculous.

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't noticed that it was transferred here in superuser. since this question is already closed. I'll try to check each suggestions you have.